# change subplot dimension of existing subplots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given an existing figure of subplots of some dimension (e.g. 1 row x 9 col) how can I change it to a new dimension (subplots of 3 row x 3 col).

This use case arises when using a plotting library which does not expose this control to the user ([Nilearn.plotting.plot_prob_atlas](http://nilearn.github.io/modules/generated/nilearn.plotting.plot_prob_atlas.html#nilearn.plotting.plot_prob_atlas) for example).  Initially creating the figure with the appropriate subplot dimensions, to my knowledge, is not possible.

Comment: `nilearn.plotting.plot_prob_atlas` has an argument `axes`. Does this not allow to customize the output in the desired way? If it really doesn't, a code sample showing the undesired behaviour would sure be useful.

Comment: Ideally I'd be interested in reshaping the subplots post-hoc, as described above, rather than digging in the internals of plot_prob_atlas which won't generalize to another problem.  But here are some details on my particular issue: nilearn.plotting does accept an axes so I had tried initializing a subplot to the appropriate size and plotting each slice one by one by passing the appropriate ax.  This approach hangs, but even if it did work there is no color correspondence between slices (region 1 may be blue in one slice and red in another) because of the multiple calls.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there isn't a better method for the specific problem of aranging subplots from nilearn.plotting.

In general, let's consider you have a blackbox function that returns a figure with some subplots. You will need to know the number of subplots it creates though. 
You can then create a new grid and set the position of the axes in the figure to the positions of that new grid.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec
import numpy as np

# blackbox function that returns a figure with 9 subplots in a row
def blackbox():
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=9)
    for ax in axes:
        a = np.random.rand(10,10)
        ax.pcolormesh(a, vmin=0, vmax=1)
    return fig


fig = blackbox()

gs = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(3,3)
for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
    ax.set_position(gs[i].get_position(fig))

plt.show()
```